# Convert varchar to datetime without millisecond

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Write simple this query:

```
select cast('2020-10-10 07:30:00.0000000' as datetime)
```

and want to show

> '2020-10-10 07:30:00'

but SQL Server return this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

How can solve that problem? Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, For `datetime`, the valid time ranges `00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997 `. What you want as `07:30:00` is just presentation issue. Do the formatting at your front end application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `datetime` doesn't have that level of precision, instead use `datetime2`:

```
select cast('2020-10-10 07:30:00.0000000' as datetime2);
```

And to only show the desired string, cast it to a shorter string:

```
select cast(cast('2020-10-10 07:30:00.0000000' as datetime2) as varchar(19));
```

Obviously it makes no sense to cast a string to date and back again, but I assume you have simplified your actual use-case. Otherwise you could use:

```
select cast('2020-10-10 07:30:00.0000000' as varchar(19));
```

Comment: thanks your code work,i accept your answer soon